# Using Python with Bluetooth on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: python, bluetooth, pi-3, keyboard

Following [this tutorial](http://www.linuxuser.co.uk/tutorials/emulate-a-bluetooth-keyboard-with-the-raspberry-pi) I successfully ran PiTooth on the RPi2MB (Wheezy).

Following the same tutorial on the RPi3MB (Jessie) I get the following message "Could not configure bluetooth. Is bluetoothd started?", which is a part of step 11 from the tutorial.

Executing `systemctl status bluetooth` shows:

```
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled)
Active: active (running)
```

I also tried restarting bluetooth using `sudo hcitool down` then `sudo hcitool up` and `systemctl stop bluetooth` then `systemctl start bluetooth`.

I followed this [guide](https://learn.adafruit.com/install-bluez-on-the-raspberry-pi/installation) to install bluez on top executing `sudo apt-get install pi-bluetooth`

and

`sudo apt-get install python-gobject bluez bluez-tools bluez-firmware python-bluez python-dev python-pip`

Note: the RPi3 doesn't support Wheezy.
I'm also trying to use the built-in bluetooth and not an external adapter.

Thanks in advance!